# Python flask static status 304

Tags: python-3.x, flask, http-status

O `flask` está me retornando o seguinte `error`:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Jun/2019 22:55:07] "GET /destino/17 HTTP/1.1" 200 - 
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Jun/2019 22:55:07] "GET /static/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - 
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Jun/2019 22:55:07] "GET /static/css/bootstrap/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - 
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Jun/2019 22:55:07] "GET /static/css/gaia/main.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

Segue o meu `HTML`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap/bootstrap-reboot.min.css') }}">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap/bootstrap-grid.min.css') }}">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css') }}">
    <!-- Ga.IA -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/gaia/main.css') }}">
    <title>Ga.IA</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
    </div>

<footer class="footer">
    <p class="navbar-brand">Versão: {{ sistema['versao'] }} - 2019 (c) - Bruno La Porta</p>
</footer>

    <!-- jQuery primeiro, depois Popper.js, depois Bootstrap JS -->
    <script type="text/plain" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/plain" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery/jquery.mask.min.js') }}"></script>
    <!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>-->
    <script type="text/plain" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
    <!-- DataTable -->
    <script type="text/plain" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery/jquery.dataTables.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/plain" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js') }}"></script>
    <!-- Sweet Alert -->
    <script type="text/plain" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/sweet_alert/sweetalert.min.js') }}"></script>
    <!-- Ga.IA -->
    <script type="text/plain" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/gaia/main.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/plain" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/gaia/usuario.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/plain" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/gaia/cliente.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Nota**

> Os scripts `javascript` devem ficar como `type="text/plain"`, caso contrário retornariam o mesmo `error`. Já tentei utilizar o `type` no `css` e até mesmo removendo todos, porém o tipo de `error` é o mesmo.

Comment: Bruno, você tentou limpar o cache completo do seu browser?

Comment: @THIAGODEBONIS eu tentei abrir em outro navegador limpo, o erro persistiu.

Comment: Só para garantir tente fazer uma limpeza completa e depois da limpeza você aperta `CTRL + R` que é o mesmo que `F5`, depois você me fala se persiste.

Comment: @THIAGODEBONIS, acabei de fazer, eles estão retornando corretamente, porem abri o console do navegador, ele esta me retornando um erro no `JQuery` e quando tento acessar uma pagina ele acusa erro no `bootstrap.min.js`.

Comment: Bruno, poste esse `error` na sua pergunta, assim fica mais fácil de te ajudar. Então o `error` atual da pegunta não possui mais né?

Comment: @THIAGODEBONIS, farei uma nova pergunta referente ao `js` e aos erros que ocorrem, pois estava funcionando, alterei apenas o `type` dos links e pronto, começou o problema com o cache e agora com o `bootstrap` e `jquery`, e estes não foram resolvidos com esta limpeza do cache, muito obrigado pelas dicas e pela disposição, abrirei uma nova pergunta e referenciarei esta.

Comment: Compreendi, irei te ajudar na próxima pergunta.. Como fui eu quem entrou em contato com  você, eu respondi a sua pergunta após isto, caso você ache correto poderia considerar a mesma como a certa e me dar uma pontuação na mesma? Isto é claro se você considerar que a mesma é realmente a correta..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**O código `304` de HTTP não é de erro**, na verdade nenhum código no intervalo do 3xx será erro, todos são sobre redirecionamentos.

No caso o flask já implementa sistema de `E-tag` ou `if-modified` nos headers para **arquivos estáticos**, então no seu navegador quando acessa algo estático será salvo os valores dos headers citados e toda vez que o navegador tentar acessar o mesmo arquivo ele envia os "valores" de volta, se os valores casarem com os do lado do servidor é enviado uma página vazia com o código 304, indicando que a cópia cache do estático salvo no computador do usuário é igual ao do servidor e por isso o download não é mais necessário.

Após isso o navegador irá usar o arquivo "cache" como se tivesse sido baixado.

---

### Em ambiente de desenvolvimento

Se quiser evitar o cache em ambiente de desenvolvimento você pode simplesmente abrir o console (F12 no chrome) e selecionar esta opção:

[image: Disable cache in chrome]

Se estiver usando Apache pode colocar em seu `.htaccess` algo como (exemplo apenas para css e js estáticos):

```
<filesMatch "\.(?i:css|js)$">
  FileETag None
  <ifModule mod_headers.c>
     Header unset ETag
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
     Header set Pragma "no-cache"
     Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
  </ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

Se for puramente via Flask (linha de comando no terminal) edite o teu arquivo principal do flask semelhante a isto http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.get_send_file_max_age da própria documentação, no seu caso ficando assim para JS e CSS:

```
class BrunoFlask(flask.Flask):
    def get_send_file_max_age(self, name):
        lname = name.lower()

        if lname.endswith('.js') or lname.endswith('.css'):
            return 0 # tempo de cache dos js e css será de 0 segundos

        return flask.Flask.get_send_file_max_age(self, name)
```

> **Nota:** o uso de `get_send_file_max_age` pode atender o Apache ou Ngnix também

Comment: Pois então, antes funcionava sem nenhum problema, depois que fiz uma alteração comecei a receber este status, digo `erro` pois simplesmente não funciona, ele esta quebrando a minha aplicação, testei inclusive em outros navegadores, porém o mesmo resultado.

Comment: @bruno101 quebrando como? Esta no apache ou direto pelo Flask?

Comment: @bruno101 veja a edição.

Comment: Estou usando direto pelo flask, porém quando jogo a aplicação para o servidor, lá eu uso o `NGINX`, porém lá não estava dando nenhum problema, estas quebras começaram a ocorrer no `localhost` apenas, ceio que ainda caiba fazer duas perguntas, pois ele esta retornando erros (vi pelo console) nos `JS` do `jquery` e `bootstrap`.

Comment: @bruno101 quebrando como? "Quebrar" pode ser qualquer coisa, não dá para entender bem, o que quer dizer, o CSS em cache não carrega? É isso? Já que é em localhost via terminal usa o get_send_file_max_age  como expliquei na resposta. Deve ajudar, mas não use em produção, ok?

Comment: Vou comentar aqui o erro que acontece, em uma das paginas eu tenho uma `collapse` de onde eu peguei o exemplo do site do `bootstrap` mesmo, ela estava funcionando até aparecerem estes retornos 3xx, agora ao clicar para expandir a `collapse` ela mostra o seguinte erro no console (chrome):

Comment: bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null
    at a.t._getParent (bootstrap.min.js:6)
    at new a (bootstrap.min.js:6)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap.min.js:6)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
    at k.fn.init.each (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
    at k.fn.init.a._jQueryInterface [as collapse] (bootstrap.min.js:6)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap.min.js:6)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
    at k.fn.init.each (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap.min.js:6)

Comment: Caro @bruno101 isso ai é outro erro, tem nada haver com cache, simplesmente algum erro no teu .js: main.js, usuario.js ou cliente.js, não tem como sabermos sem que poste o que tentou fazer, mas já lhe adianto, provavelmente tentou executar um script fora de `$(function () {...})` ou sem esperar o load da página, logo o script tenta acessar um elemento que ainda não renderizou.

Comment: Eu não sei o que um tem a ver com outro, mas elas pararam de funcionar quando alterei os `type` dos `css` e `js`, então estes começaram a dar este retorno 3xx e as `collapses` pararam de responder (dando aquele erro), limpando o cache do navegador os `css` e `js` voltarama  retornar 200, porém ainda persiste as `collapses`.

Comment: Creio que caiba fazer uma pergunta referente apenas ao `js`, vou aprovar a resposta e abrir uma nova pergunta, muito obrigado.

Comment: Caro @bruno101 não se resolve o problema aplicando outro problema, isso ai tá errado,, aliás o type="text/plain" nem é para scripts, o que vc tem que resolver é o que eu falei, arranca esses type="" tudo dos <script>, deixa sem, e procura no teu HTML o atributo `data-parent=` (deve estar em alguma "view" sua), ele deve estar com um valor errado e por isso o colapse não funciona.

Comment: Os scripts e os links css estão sem o `type`, da seguinte forma agora:
`<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/gaia/main.js') }}"></script>`, ou seja, agora esta como antes de ocorrer estes problemas, porém o ficou este residual, poderia colocar aqui nesta pergunta também, mas acredito que ficaria muito bagunçado.

Answer (score 1):

A resposta `HTTP 304` é para **"Redirecionamento para um resultado armazenado em cache anteriormente"**.

Isso significa que o `Flask` está dizendo ao seu browser que o mesmo já possui o determinado conteúdo.

Para resolver o seu problema, faça o seguinte:

- Limpe totalmente o cache do seu browser
- Para garantir, após o primeiro passo, aperte a tecla de atalho `CTRL + R`, o qual terá o mesmo efeito do `F5`.

Após estes passos o seu problema estará solucionado e você perceberá que o `Flask` retornará um `status 200` na sua próxima solicitação.

**Nota**

> Sugiro a você que desabilite no modo desenvolver do seu browser o Cache, assim você não precisará ficar lembrando de limpar o mesmo toda hora.

Comment: Mas você respondeu tudo o que eu já havia respondido e aliás o problema do autor nem era esse. PS: o downvote não é meu, ok? :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento na verdade se você verificar nos comentários da Pergunta, irá perceber que eu estava em contato com o usuário e tudo que você disse ali eu já tinha falado.

Comment: Caro thiago, seus comentários falam sobre limpar cache, que aliás nem é a solução e realmente lá não fala nada sobre o que é o 304 ou qualquer coisa assim.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento na verdade eu já sabia a solução, só estava confirmando com ele, após ele ter feito todos os procedimentos o qual falei resolveu o problema dele abordado na pergunta, o outro problema é referente a outro assunto, tanto que ele mesmo afirma e irá fazer uma outra pergunta para isto. Mas você está com a pergunta checara como a certa, não se preocupe rss.

Comment: Não é sobre score, não é sobre qualquer coisa assim, é sobre você responder algo que já foi respondido, sem complementar nada... eu não brigo por score, eu estou te orientando, eu sei uma série de respostas, aliás com conhecimento técnico, mas se outra pessoa já respondeu não tem sentido ir lá e responder novamente, a não ser que você venha a complementa-la. Compreende?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento também não estou brigando por score, só estou tentando te explicar que o problema citado já estava na pergunta, e geralmente esse problema é pelo o que nos falamos, só estou tentando te explicar que eu já estava em comunicação com o usuário antes de você responder e estava confirmando o que tinha dito no comentário para elaborar a minha resposta que já estava pronta. Eu não vi que você tinha respondido, pois eu já estava com outra aba aberta na parte de inserir resposta. Peace brow!

Comment: Caro Thiago eu náo disse que vc esta brigando, e nem muito menos eu estou brigando/discutindo, brigar por algo se refere a correr atrás, eu não corro atrás de score. Entendeu? Não estou discutindo contigo, estou explicando o que pode ser ou não util a comunidade, o resto expliquei bem no meu primeiro e segundo comentários.